# How to created 3d text with square ridged border in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, 3d

I want to make 3d text in photoshop that has a thick square border, with a different color than the text, very similar to this:

[image]

I've been playing with these contour settings:

[image]

But this is the closest I can get:

[image]

Is this effect possible to achieve within photoshop?

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume that the original was also done with Photoshop? It looks to me Illustrator would be the better choice. (Or possibly a 3D renderer.)

Comment: i dont know, was just hoping it would be possible since it seems pretty simple / common